# og:image could not be downloaded or is too small

Tags: joomla-3.4, facebook

last week Facebook was not fetching post image, then suddenly it start fetching after 48hrs. Yesterday another issue appeared which is;

When I share link on fb it give me the choice between 3 images instead of fetching real image. I have not changed anything in settings.

Here is [debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemedia24.com%2Fvideos%2F7730-imran-khan-vs-altaf-hussain-funny-rap-battle)

I am using Joomla 3.4, and Easy like and Share module.

Comment: Debug looks fine - Fb sharing looks fine. What is the issue?

Comment: I debugged above url three times and finally it fetched exact same image. It looks fine cuz its in fb cache now. Here you can see the issue: http://www.livemedia24.com/videos/7734-khan-sahab-bohot-sharmillay-hain-reham-khan and i have not fetched new information. as i mention When I share link on fb it give me the choice between 3 images instead of fetching real image.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/9867/120 ?