# Is something wrong with Joomla with Facebook?

Tags: joomla-3.4, facebook

Please have a look on [Facebook Debug result](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemedia24.com%2Fvideos%2F7808-this-boy-got-talent)

I dont know why it is not fetching correct image, whenever i share url on facebook it give me three choice of image instead of real image.

I googled alot even search Joomla forum but did not find any solution. Can someone please help? I am using Joomla 3.4 along with RsSocial Module. Gzip is disable in Global Configuration.

It was working fine since few months and suddenly this happened, even I have not changed any settings or scripts. I also tested few social modules but still same issue. OG tags are properly mention as you can see.

As you can see there is wrong image, for temporary I always hit Fetch new information four times to fetch right image.

Comment: When I click the share button in your page, it shows the image you have defined to be posted. Have you cleared Joomla caches?

Comment: Yes I always clear cache whenever i update my site, yeah the above link is showing right image now, i guess someone hit fetch new information, which I already mention. Here is another url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemedia24.com%2Fvideos%2F7808-this-boy-got-talent as you can see it fecthed image but wrong one. And you can check path to right image.

Comment: This url also gave me the correct image when shared. Are these just fresh posts without prior been scrapped by FB?

Comment: The url I gave you in above comment is scrapped by FB, and it is fetching image but wrong one. Here is right image path http://www.livemedia24.com/media/com_hwdmediashare/files/2b/ca/cf/326e118fb3fc0805eefc3e7858703eae.png Facebook sharing was working fine but it suddenly happened since week. I dont know why it is fetching wrong image.

Comment: As you can see here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemedia24.com%2Fvideos%2F7808-this-boy-got-talent it is showing wrong image below "When shared, this is what will be included" but the right image path is http://www.livemedia24.com/media/com_hwdmediashare/files/2b/ca/cf/326e118fb3fc0805eefc3e7858703eae.png But if I will hit Fetch new information four times then it will fetch right image. But I never ever experienced this situation. Week ago I was simply hitting share button and it was fetching right image.

Comment: What it comes to my mind, seeing also the errors in fb debugger is that if these are fresh posts, the first time you ask FB to scrap the page maybe the image file that exists in the og:image meta is not yet ready - not accessible to be read. Maybe your extension creates the image on the fly after it is being asked for it.

Comment: Yes I agree with your comment. But strange thing is that it was working fine since couple of months and it suddenly happend since week. Whenever I hit like button Fb scrapper fetch the wrong image. So Whenever I have to share that url on page I always have to hit fetch new information four time then it fetch correct image, now matter how old is url.

Comment: I can not fetch all urls cuz there are many editors are working on site and adding aprx 100+ content and it is impossible for me to fetch new information of 100+ urls

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/9843/120 ?